# Using pandoc for latex on WSL: package problems

Tags: windows, linux

I am attempting to adopt a system where pandoc generates latex files through commands in WSL.  But whenever I attempt to generate the PDF files, every package is not loaded on the fly.  Miktex works perfectly on windows using texmaker but isn't accessed by pandoc i assume.  Is there any way to add those packages to WSL?

On a side-note, livetex for linux was installed as well in bash, but it doesn't seem to help.

edit:
If it helps, I have a Makefile and I'm using the bash make command.  I'm new to this, and I'm not 100% sure what's relevant.

Comment: Most likely an interop issue since paths will be different e.g. " File paths must be specified in the WSL format." some hints here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop

Comment: I wouldn't say so.  using "which latex.exe" returns a path that linux should respond.

Comment: I do not run WSL so much on my part is conjecture and reading the guide there are references to changes from win version to version so WSLENV may or may not be available. In such a case I would not simply trust which although I often recommend for checking path to a exe it does not confirm which objects ARE first on runtime path etc. in native windows a simple cmd file with path &  pause can help to see what happens during execution however not sure what the wsl equivalent would be

Comment: I would definitely use the wsl texlive not miktex or windows texlive. Native windows applications will have trouble with posix file permissions as used in the linux subsystem, it might be OK but using the wsl tex will be safer and simpler. @agenttiny200 the wsl latex will have name latex not latex.exe